# How to append header to the data in csv file created by python dataframe

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I have data available in a dataframe

```
EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,AGE
1,X,71
2,Y,70
3,Z,78
```

How can i convert above data into below format

```
EMP_ID:1|EMP_NAME:X|AGE:71
EMP_ID:2|EMP_NAME:Y|AGE:70
EMP_ID:3|EMP_NAME:Z|AGE:78
```

#

Viceversa Scenario:

Can we convert the below data

```
EMP_ID:1|EMP_NAME:X|AGE:71
EMP_ID:2|EMP_NAME:Y|AGE:70
EMP_ID:3|EMP_NAME:Z|AGE:78
```

again back to

```
EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,AGE
1,X,71
2,Y,70
3,Z,78
```

Comment: *data available in a dataframe* - but the 1st fragment looks more like a raw csv data

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest. Yes roman  i have dataframe in that format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the most efficient option, but you could just loop through the dataframes columns and then apply a basic function to each.

Note: all your columns must be a string now.

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: col +':' + str(x))
```

And to reverse it, use a similar logic using string slicing:

```
for col in df.columns: 
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x[len(col)+1:])
```

Comment: df[col] = df2[col]  ---- I see two different dataframe , can you help me to explain

Comment: It was a typo! Sorry!

Comment: Thanks a lot. . Without loop is there any other best way

Comment: How can we do it in vice versa

Comment: @Arya what do you mean vice versa?

Comment: I have updated the question for vice versa scenario. I want to convert EMP_ID:1|EMP_NAME:X|AGE:71  --> 1,X,71

Answer (score 1):

df.columns=df.columns+'|'+df.iloc[0,:]